# Licensing SQL 2008 R2 Processor License while SQL 2012 is available only

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, licensing, sql-server-2012

We are looking to install SQL Server 2008 R2 - given that the licensing model has changed ever since SQL 2012 came out (Processor licenses no longer available) and the 2008 R2 Processor license no longer being available..

I was wondering, is it valid to purchase SQL Server 2008 R2 Processor Licenses off on-line stores (not the Microsoft Marketplace obviously) shops to acquire the licenses - will there be any knock-back from MS should an auditor come over to check the licensing?

Bottom line is, given our setup - Server/User Licenses are not interesting to us.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

We're not lawyers, and this site isn't for legal advice or questions about licensing compliance. I strongly recommend you don't gamble your company's future on believing an answer you get on a Q & A site from some anonymous person on the Internet.

The proper way to be sure is to contact an official Microsoft licensing rep, tell them what you are buying and where, and have them confirm that you will be compliant - before you buy.

http://support.microsoft.com/contactus/cu_sc_prodinfo_master